# JSP tag file doesn't recognize #{} syntax

Tags: jsp, jsf, el, jsp-tags, myfaces

In my JSP page I'm using the following line to retrieve a label:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="com.me.resources.test" var="mytest" />
<h:outputLabel value= "#{mytest.mylabel}"/>
```

and it's working great!

I'd like to do the same in a JSP tag file `myTemplate.tag`, but here the same code doesn't work, it displays exactly `#{mytest.mylabel}`.

The template is correctly loaded in the JSP page.

I've tried also with a Facelets, but it doesn't display anything: here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  >

<h:body>
Hello
<f:loadBundle basename="com.me.resources.test" var="mytest" />
<h:outputText value= "#{mytest.mylabel}"/>

</h:body>
```

In this case it displays only "Hello".

Have you got any ideas where is the problem?

I'm using MyFaces 2.1.10

Comment: Why exactly are you still using the since 2009 deprecated JSP view technology instead of its successor Facelets?

Comment: i know it's deprecated...but i didn't write this code by myself, so i must need it...

Comment: I'm trying also with a Facelets, but it doesn't work:

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >

 <f:loadBundle basename="com.me.resources.test" var="mytest"/>


    <h:body>
 
 <ui:define name="content">

 <h:outputText value= "#{mytest.mylabel}"/>

Comment: so I suppose it works only with jsp file...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `${mytest.mylabel}` instead of `#{mytest.mylabel}`?

Please refer to [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahr.html).